# Does the second derivative exist at zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $$f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{ if } x < 0\\ 2x+x^2 & \text{ if } x \ge 0\end{cases}$$

Then do I have to check whether $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ exist or not?

So, by definition of derivatives, $f'(0)$ does not exist as limit from left is zero and from right is $2$? So $f'$ does not exist on $0$, but does that mean, $f''$ also cannot exist at $0$. I am a bit confused here. Because on $x<0$, it seems that $f''=2$ and at $x\ge 0$ , $f''=2$ so $f''=2\ \forall\ x\in \Bbb{R}$.

The options had

1. $f''=2\ \forall\ x\in \Bbb{R}$.
2. $f''(0)$ does not exist
3. $f'$ exists for each $x\neq 0$
4. $f'(0)$ does not exist.

So either 2, 3 and 4 is correct or 1,3 and 4 is correct.

But if $f'$ does not exist at $0$, we cannot talk about $f''$ at zero, right?

Comment: Since $f'$ is not continuous at $0$, $f''(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: The definition of the second derivative is the rate of change of the first derivative. This definition is important, as you can make "fake" upper derivatives by using a higher order limit. Since your first derivative does not exist here, it has no limit to apply.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=2x+2$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=2x\neq2x+2$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f''(x)=2=\lim_{x\to0^-}f''(x)$$
$f''(0) \ $could exist if you allow Dirac delta, though.

Comment: There is no reason to use  x < 0 for f(x)= x^2. Using <= 0 makes f continuous and f'' = 2 for all x.

Comment: I might add that f'' can be defined as a meaesure of the curvature of f and this is 2 everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find $f(x_0)$ by definition we have to find  $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$. In our case $x_0=0$, $$\lim_{h \to 0+} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0-} \frac{2h + h^2-0}{h} = 2$$ and $$\lim_{h \to 0-} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0-} \frac{h^2-0}{h} = 0.$$ It follows that  $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$ doesn't exist. Hence, $f'(0)$ doesn't exist. Moreover, $f''(0)$ doesn't exist because $f'(0)$ doesn't exist.